# R Column for cumulative frequency of a row's particular item

Tags: r, frequency

I'm trying to create a column that counts the frequency of that particular row's value up to that point. The code for each matrix shows the current data and the desired results. So for a matrix of columns Type | Value:

```
test <- matrix(c(
1,0.14,
1,0.1345,
2,1.245,
2,1.532,
3,3.5345,
3,2.987,
2,1.743),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

colnames(test) <- c("Type", "Value")
```

I'm trying to get an output frequency column that corresponds to the type column:

```
test <- matrix(c(
1,0.14,1,
1,0.1345,2,
2,1.245,1,
2,1.532,2,
3,3.5345,1,
3,2.987,2,
2,1.743,3),ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

colnames(test) <- c("Type", "Value","Frequency")
```

For each sum of Type that came before there is a cumulative count in that row. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show what the expected outcome is?

Comment: Hi @raistlin. The second block of code is the expected outcome, with an extra column called "Frequency" that has a count of each type that has come before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to group the data by `Type` and then return the row number for each line. Because the data are grouped, the row number will equal the number of times the given value of `Type` has appeared.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(Frequency = row_number())
```

Comment: In the event that there was a date metric that it must be ordered in as well, would you advise sorting the data by type, creating corresponding frequency values and then sorting it back into date order?

Comment: This code doesn't require the data to be sorted by `Type`. Note the last row of your sample data. It has a 2 for `Type` and the Frequency still counts it as the third time that a 2 has been used.

Comment: That's great! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way:

```
> Frequency<-sapply(1:nrow(test), function(i) sum(test[1:i,1]==test[i,1]))
> cbind(test, Frequency)
     Type  Value Frequency
[1,]    1 0.1400         1
[2,]    1 0.1345         2
[3,]    2 1.2450         1
[4,]    2 1.5320         2
[5,]    3 3.5345         1
[6,]    3 2.9870         2
[7,]    2 1.7430         3
```

Comment: This is a pretty handy alternative. Thanks very much!